# Is there a way to separate an object by material?

Tags: materials

I've downloaded an OBJ. file that is all one object besides the materials. Is there a way I can separate them out so I can delete them?

[image: My screen]

Comment: Absolutely. Switch to *Edit Mode* (`Tab`), press `a` to select everything, press `p` and choose *By Material*.

Comment: The method @brockmann describes is the best to split up the complete object by its materials. Another possibility if you want some pieces staying together although they have two or more different materials would be to go into _Edit Mode_,  hit _Alt+A_ to deselect everything, then choose a material, hit the _Select_ button under the material slots, then choose another material, _Select_ etc. then go into the 3D Viewport, hit _P_ > _Separate Selection_.